# How to change gauge meter color based on value in highcharts

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I have a gauge meter chart in highcharts, here I want to change the color of needle based on value while rotating.

Here below is my code:

```js
$(function() {

  $('#container').highcharts({
      chart: {
        type: 'gauge',
      },
      title: {
        text: 'PV Generation'
      },
      tooltip: {
        enabled: false
      },
      pane: {
        center: ['50%', '55%'],
        size: '75%',
        startAngle: -100,
        endAngle: 100,
        background: {
          backgroundColor: '#aaaaaa',
          innerRadius: '95%',
          outerRadius: '100%',
          shape: 'arc',
        },
      },

      yAxis: [{
        lineWidth: 0,
        min: 0,
        max: 900,
        tickInterval: 50,
        tickPosition: 'outside',
        minorTickPosition: 'outside',
        tickLength: 15,
        minorTickLength: 5,
        labels: {
          distance: 25,
        },
        offset: 5,
        endOnTick: false,
        title: {
          y: -70
        },

        plotOptions: {
          solidgauge: {
            dataLabels: {
              y: 5,
              borderWidth: 0,
              useHTML: true
            }
          }
        },
        plotBands: [{
          from: 0,
          to: 250,
          color: '#55BF3B' // green
        }, {
          from: 250,
          to: 700,
          color: '#DDDF0D', // yellow
          series: [{
            data: [{
              id: 'hour',
              y: 400,
              yAxis: 0,
              dial: {
                backgroundColor: '#000000',
                color: 'red',
                radius: '100%',
                baseWidth: 10,
                baseLength: '5%',
                baseWidth: 15,
                rearLength: '0%',
              }
            }]
          }]
        }, {
          from: 700,
          to: 900,
          color: '#DF5353' // red
        }]

      }],
      series: [{
        name: 'Speed',
        data: [{
          y: 450
        }]
      }]
    },
    // Add some life
    function(chart) {
      setInterval(function() {
        var point = chart.series[0].points[0],
          newVal,
          inc = Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 20);

        newVal = point.y + 4 * inc;
        if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 900) {
          newVal = point.y - 4 * inc;
        }

        chart.yAxis[0].removePlotBand('plot-band-1');
        chart.yAxis[0].addPlotBand({
          from: 0,
          to: newVal,
          // color: '#000000',
          thickness: '10%',
          id: 'plot-band-1'
        });
        point.update(newVal);
      }, 4000);

    });


  $("#container").find("circle").attr("r", 15);
  $("#container").find("circle").attr("fill", "red");
  // $("#container").find("series").data("fill", "black");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by changing some parts of your update code. I have done the following:

Remove `point.update(newVal)`

Add an update that updates the needle, the pivot and the value based on if the value is increasing or decreasing:

```
if (inc > 0) {
  chart.series[0].update({
    dial: {
      backgroundColor: 'green',
    },
    pivot: {
      backgroundColor: 'green'
    },
    data: [{
      y: newVal
    }]
  }, true);
} else {
  chart.series[0].update({
    dial: {
      backgroundColor: 'red',
    },
    pivot: {
      backgroundColor: 'red'
    },
    data: [{
      y: newVal
    }]
  }, true);
}
```

Additionally, I removed this:

```
$("#container").find("circle").attr("r", 15);
$("#container").find("circle").attr("fill", "red");
```

And instead put this in the series definition:

```
series: [{
  name: 'Speed',
  data: [{
    y: 450
  }],
  pivot: {
    radius: 15,
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  }
}]
```

That way it is a highchart property and will not get overwritten when we update the the series.

**API refs:** [series.gauge](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.gauge) and [Highcharts.update](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#update)

---

**Full working example:**

```js
$(function() {

  $('#container').highcharts({
      chart: {
        type: 'gauge',
      },
      title: {
        text: 'PV Generation'
      },
      tooltip: {
        enabled: false
      },
      pane: {
        center: ['50%', '55%'],
        size: '75%',
        startAngle: -100,
        endAngle: 100,
        background: {
          backgroundColor: '#aaaaaa',
          innerRadius: '95%',
          outerRadius: '100%',
          shape: 'arc',
        },
      },
      yAxis: [{
        lineWidth: 0,
        min: 0,
        max: 900,
        tickInterval: 50,
        tickPosition: 'outside',
        minorTickPosition: 'outside',
        tickLength: 15,
        minorTickLength: 5,
        labels: {
          distance: 25,
        },
        offset: 5,
        endOnTick: false,
        title: {
          y: -70
        },
        plotOptions: {
          solidgauge: {
            dataLabels: {
              y: 5,
              borderWidth: 0,
              useHTML: true
            }
          }
        },
        plotBands: [{
          from: 0,
          to: 250,
          color: '#55BF3B' // green
        }, {
          from: 250,
          to: 700,
          color: '#DDDF0D', // yellow
          series: [{
            data: [{
              id: 'hour',
              y: 400,
              yAxis: 0,
              dial: {
                backgroundColor: '#000000',
                color: 'red',
                radius: '100%',
                baseWidth: 10,
                baseLength: '5%',
                baseWidth: 15,
                rearLength: '0%',
              }
            }]
          }]
        }, {
          from: 700,
          to: 900,
          color: '#DF5353' // red
        }]
      }],
      series: [{
        name: 'Speed',
        data: [{
          y: 450
        }],
        pivot: {
          radius: 15,
          backgroundColor: 'red'
        }
      }]
    },
    // Add some life
    function(chart) {
      setInterval(function() {
        var point = chart.series[0].points[0],
          newVal,
          inc = Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 20);
        newVal = point.y + 4 * inc;
        if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 900) {
          newVal = point.y - 4 * inc;
        }
        chart.yAxis[0].removePlotBand('plot-band-1');
        chart.yAxis[0].addPlotBand({
          from: 0,
          to: newVal,
          // color: '#000000',
          thickness: '10%',
          id: 'plot-band-1'
        });
        if (inc > 0) {
          chart.series[0].update({
            dial: {
              backgroundColor: 'green',
            },
            pivot: {
              backgroundColor: 'green'
            },
            data: [{
              y: newVal
            }]
          }, true);
        } else {
          chart.series[0].update({
            dial: {
              backgroundColor: 'red',
            },
            pivot: {
              backgroundColor: 'red'
            },

            data: [{
              y: newVal
            }]
          }, true);
        }
      }, 4000);

    });


  //$("#container").find("circle").attr("r", 15);
  //$("#container").find("circle").attr("fill", "red");
  // $("#container").find("series").data("fill", "black");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

---

**Edit to deal with ranges per color:**

I.e. *0 - 250: green*, *250-700: yellow*, *700-900: red*

```js
$(function() {

  $('#container').highcharts({
      chart: {
        type: 'gauge',
      },
      title: {
        text: 'PV Generation'
      },
      tooltip: {
        enabled: false
      },
      pane: {
        center: ['50%', '55%'],
        size: '75%',
        startAngle: -100,
        endAngle: 100,
        background: {
          backgroundColor: '#aaaaaa',
          innerRadius: '95%',
          outerRadius: '100%',
          shape: 'arc',
        },
      },
      yAxis: [{
        lineWidth: 0,
        min: 0,
        max: 900,
        tickInterval: 50,
        tickPosition: 'outside',
        minorTickPosition: 'outside',
        tickLength: 15,
        minorTickLength: 5,
        labels: {
          distance: 25,
        },
        offset: 5,
        endOnTick: false,
        title: {
          y: -70
        },
        plotOptions: {
          solidgauge: {
            dataLabels: {
              y: 5,
              borderWidth: 0,
              useHTML: true
            }
          }
        },
        plotBands: [{
          from: 0,
          to: 250,
          color: '#55BF3B' // green
        }, {
          from: 250,
          to: 700,
          color: '#DDDF0D', // yellow
          series: [{
            data: [{
              id: 'hour',
              y: 400,
              yAxis: 0,
              dial: {
                backgroundColor: '#000000',
                color: 'red',
                radius: '100%',
                baseWidth: 10,
                baseLength: '5%',
                baseWidth: 15,
                rearLength: '0%',
              }
            }]
          }]
        }, {
          from: 700,
          to: 900,
          color: '#DF5353' // red
        }]
      }],
      series: [{
        name: 'Speed',
        data: [{
          y: 450
        }],
        dial: {
              backgroundColor: '#DDDF0D',
            },
        pivot: {
          radius: 15,
          backgroundColor: '#DDDF0D'
        }
      }]
    },
    // Add some life
    function(chart) {
      setInterval(function() {
        var point = chart.series[0].points[0],
          newVal,
          inc = Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 20);
        newVal = point.y + 4 * inc;
        if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 900) {
          newVal = point.y - 4 * inc;
        }
        chart.yAxis[0].removePlotBand('plot-band-1');
        chart.yAxis[0].addPlotBand({
          from: 0,
          to: newVal,
          // color: '#000000',
          thickness: '10%',
          id: 'plot-band-1'
        });
        if (newVal < 250) {
          chart.series[0].update({
            dial: {
              backgroundColor: 'green',
            },
            pivot: {
              backgroundColor: 'green'
            },
            data: [{
              y: newVal
            }]
          }, true);
        } else if(newVal > 250 && newVal < 700){
          chart.series[0].update({
            dial: {
              backgroundColor: '#DDDF0D',
            },
            pivot: {
              backgroundColor: '#DDDF0D'
            },
            data: [{
              y: newVal
            }]
          }, true);
        } else {
          chart.series[0].update({
            dial: {
              backgroundColor: 'red',
            },
            pivot: {
              backgroundColor: 'red'
            },

            data: [{
              y: newVal
            }]
          }, true);
        }
      }, 4000);

    });


  //$("#container").find("circle").attr("r", 15);
  //$("#container").find("circle").attr("fill", "red");
  // $("#container").find("series").data("fill", "black");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much,but actually I need to change the color of needle based on the  range for ex : 0 - 250 color will be green,250 - 700 color will be yellow and 700 -900 color will be red

Comment: I have updated now to support this. See the bottom of the answer for the example.

Comment: Thanks..it was very helpful for me

Answer (score 2):

You can use `events.render` function to detect the value of `y` and change the color of the pointer accordingly

Updating your existing code

```
   events: {
      render: function() {
        newVal = this.series[0].data[0].y;
        graph = this.series[0].data[0].graphic;
        if (newVal >= 0 && newVal < 250) {
          graph.attr({
            fill: '#55BF3B'
          });
          this.series[0].pivot.attr({
            fill: '#55BF3B'
          });
        }
        if (newVal >= 250 && newVal < 700) {
          graph.attr({
            fill: '#DDDF0D'
          });
          this.series[0].pivot.attr({
            fill: '#DDDF0D'
          });
        }
        if (newVal >= 700 && newVal < 900) {
          graph.attr({
            fill: '#DF5353'
          });
          this.series[0].pivot.attr({
            fill: '#DF5353'
          });
        }
      }
    }
```

```js
$(function() {

  $('#container').highcharts({
      chart: {
        type: 'gauge',
        events: {
          render: function() {
            newVal = this.series[0].data[0].y;
            graph = this.series[0].data[0].graphic;
            if (newVal >= 0 && newVal < 250) {
              graph.attr({
                fill: '#55BF3B'
              });
              this.series[0].pivot.attr({
                fill: '#55BF3B'
              });
            }
            if (newVal >= 250 && newVal < 700) {
              graph.attr({
                fill: '#DDDF0D'
              });
              this.series[0].pivot.attr({
                fill: '#DDDF0D'
              });
            }
            if (newVal >= 700 && newVal < 900) {
              graph.attr({
                fill: '#DF5353'
              });
              this.series[0].pivot.attr({
                fill: '#DF5353'
              });
            }
          }
        }
      },
      title: {
        text: 'PV Generation'
      },
      tooltip: {
        enabled: false
      },
      pane: {
        center: ['50%', '55%'],
        size: '75%',
        startAngle: -100,
        endAngle: 100,
        background: {
          backgroundColor: '#aaaaaa',
          innerRadius: '95%',
          outerRadius: '100%',
          shape: 'arc',
        },
      },

      yAxis: [{
        lineWidth: 0,
        min: 0,
        max: 900,
        tickInterval: 50,
        tickPosition: 'outside',
        minorTickPosition: 'outside',
        tickLength: 15,
        minorTickLength: 5,
        labels: {
          distance: 25,
        },
        offset: 5,
        endOnTick: false,
        title: {
          y: -70
        },

        plotOptions: {
          solidgauge: {
            dataLabels: {
              y: 5,
              borderWidth: 0,
              useHTML: true
            }
          }
        },
        plotBands: [{
          from: 0,
          to: 250,
          color: '#55BF3B' // green
        }, {
          from: 250,
          to: 700,
          color: '#DDDF0D', // yellow
          series: [{
            data: [{
              id: 'hour',
              y: 400,
              yAxis: 0,
              dial: {
                backgroundColor: '#000000',
                color: 'red',
                radius: '100%',
                baseWidth: 10,
                baseLength: '5%',
                baseWidth: 15,
                rearLength: '0%',
              }
            }]
          }]
        }, {
          from: 700,
          to: 900,
          color: '#DF5353' // red
        }]

      }],
      series: [{
        name: 'Speed',
        data: [{
          y: 450
        }],
        pivot: {
          radius: 15,
        }
      }]
    },
    // Add some life
    function(chart) {
      setInterval(function() {
        var point = chart.series[0].points[0],
          newVal,
          inc = Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 20);

        newVal = point.y + 4 * inc;
        if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 900) {
          newVal = point.y - 4 * inc;
        }

        chart.yAxis[0].removePlotBand('plot-band-1');
        chart.yAxis[0].addPlotBand({
          from: 0,
          to: newVal,
          // color: '#000000',
          thickness: '10%',
          id: 'plot-band-1'
        });
        point.update(newVal);


      }, 1000);

    });


  // $("#container").find("circle").attr("r", 15);
  // $("#container").find("circle").attr("fill", "red");
  // $("#container").find("series").data("fill", "black");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/451xukky/) demo

Comment: Thanks a lot..it was really helpful for me